# Linux awk to print certain text

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a text:

```
root@AngelBeats:~# ifconfig 3g-3g
3g-3g     Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol
          inet addr:10.134.109.45  P-t-P:10.64.64.64  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13416 errors:1018 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11517 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3
          RX bytes:6614985 (6.3 MiB)  TX bytes:2788421 (2.6 MiB)
```

I want to print these texts only "6614985" and "2788421" (last line) I've tried these commands:

```
ifconfig 3g-3g | awk -F[\(\)] '/bytes/ {printf "%s",$2}'
ifconfig 3g-3g | awk -F[\(\)] '/bytes/ {printf "%s",$4}'
```

But instead the first command prints `6.3 MiB` and the second command prints `2.6 MiB` how do I get the bytes only ? Please note that the bytes keep changing as I browse the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ':' as fields separator will do the trick

```
ifconfig 3g-3g | awk -F[:\(] '/bytes/ {printf "%s",$2}'
ifconfig 3g-3g | awk -F[:\(] '/bytes/ {printf "%s",$4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ifconfig 3g-3g | awk -F[:\(] '/bytes/ {printf "%s",$2}'
```

Comment: put \ infront of it... It did not get added in answer

Comment: Please update your answer, you are quicker than I, but with syntax error

Comment: You can have multiple field delimiter... First is : and second is (... but since ( is reserve word put \(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
ifconfig eth0|awk -F'[[:space:]:]*' '/RX bytes:/{print $4, $9}'
```

Output:

```
13738134 83649201
```

This prints both value in one line... Maybe You wants to put both values into an environment variable. You can do this:

```
eval $(ifconfig eth0|awk -F'[[:space:]:]*' '/RX bytes:/{print "RX="$4, "TX="$9}')
echo $RX, $TX
```

Output:

```
13499630, 83579914
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

With just simple `grep` command and use of `cut` command together we can achieve it this way,

```
$ ifconfig 3g-3g|grep "RX bytes"|cut -d'(' -f1|cut -d':' -f2                                                                             
$ ifconfig 3g-3g|grep "RX bytes"|cut -d'(' -f2|cut -d':' -f2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ifconfig 3g-3g | grep bytes | nawk -F ":" '{print $2" "$3}' | nawk -F " " '{print $1" "$6}'
```

Not exactly stable for variying ouput  but working ;)

In general: If you need just one line just `grep` it first of all, makes things a lot easier.

Comment: @evilive my openwrt doesn't support `nawk` do you have another command to replace that?